# Advantages of REST URI over URI of querystring format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

All,

For a new project that we have started with .NET we wanted to exercise pure REST. Hence we chose .NET Web API which has been released as part of .NET Framework 4.5 (instead of WCF) with the consideration that it enables pure REST nature. But as we explored more based on our requirements, we realized that it doesn't have URI templating support that provides REST like URL formats. we were still OK as we didn't feel much bad about WebAPI having query string kind of formats.

When we engaged a new team, they started to enforce that they need REST kind of URL formats only as it is the standard norm and likes.

When asked about the enforcement they just mentioned that it is a standard and we have to adhere to it which didn't convince me.

So, I am interested to know what does REST architecture provides out of the box? Also having querystring format URI doesn't qualify to be a REST approach?

REST URI: http://myapplicationdomain.com/apps/appId

Querystring URI: http://myapplicationdomain.com/GetAps/appId={appId}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

REST is not only the URL format, and REST does not restricts you from using parameters.

One part of REST philosophy is to identify *resources*, so your *resource* has URL, and HTTP verbs (Get, Post, Delete, Put, etc.) define *operations* on this resource.
You can still use parameters, for example

http://myappfomain.com/product/?page=1&pageSize=10

It is a GET request to the list of products (since ID is not specified) and paging/sorting criteria is specified in a query string. It is perfectly correct.

Or

http://myappdomain.com/product/123/?format=json

Here you access product with the ID od #123, but request it to be returned as JSON. It is also fine.

From this perspective it is just more logical that a *resource* has its own URL. Parameters may add some specifics.

Look at it this way:
URI defines the *subject*
HTTP Verb defines the *operation* (what to do)
Query parameters provide some *specifics* (how to do it)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The REST (see wiki [Representational state transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)) "style" of the URI is there for a reason. An extract from wiki:

> **Uniform Interface**
>   ...
>     **Identification of resources** Individual resources are identified in requests, for example using URIs in web-based REST systems....
>
> **Manipulation of resources through these representations** When a client holds a representation of a resource, ... it has enough information to modify or delete the resource on the server ...

I used these cites as nice explanation of the fact, that REST style of URI is in fact about **resource** identification. We can have

1) a table in DB and
2) an ID column which allows to
3) UPDATE or DELETE the record.

The URI in REST does do the same:

1) Identify the resource type (entity/table)
2) Identify the resource ID
3) set the operation

```
HTTP Method       URI                        Operation
GET               \ResourceType\ResourceId   SELECT, READ
POST              \ResourceType              INSERT, Add, create new
PUT               \ResourceType\ResourceId   UPDATE the record with ResourceID
DELETE            \ResourceType\ResourceId   DELETE that record
```

So as we can see, the REST URI style does make sense in the complete context of the **resource** management

Comment: PUT can also insert if the client is in control of the value of the ResourceId, POST is used to insert when the server dictates the value of the resource id (and the id of the new resource is thus not known to the client when inserting).

Comment: How we use PUT or POST is not so related to the fact, the REST api URI style, is here for a reason. To identify **resource**

Comment: My point was not about the URI style, but that your table with examples is incomplete in its descriptions. `PUT to \ResourceType\ResourceId` can also be used to INSERT the record identified by ResourceId.

Comment: Do not get me wrong. I do agree with you. Your extension is correct, and it does fits to the REST definition. I was in my answer mostly targeting the explanation of the reason why to use REST style of URI...

Comment: Ok so let's agree to ... agree ... :-)